# Chat for COVID-19

Tags: discussion, chat

As we adjust to teaching online, I thought it might be useful to have a less formal place where we can share strategies for teaching mathematics, recommend hardware and software, share war stories, or simply vent.  To that end, I have created a new chatroom on MESE:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106054/math-education-in-the-time-of-covid-19